# unable to add objects to saved collection in GAE using JDO

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I have a ClassA containing an ArrayList of another ClassB

I can save a new instance of ClassA with ClassB instances also saved using JDO.
However, 
When I retrieve the instance of Class A,
I try to do like the below:

```
ClassA instance = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager().GetObjectByID( someid );
instance.GetClassBArrayList().add( new ClassB(...) );
```

I get an Exception like the below:
Uncaught exception from servlet com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found..

So I was wondering, Is it possible to add a new item to the previously saved collection?
Or was it something I missed out.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

"no matching index found"
Perhaps you need to add some index in GAE/J's datastore ?
Nothing to do with JDO